# How do I stop sharing call history between two iPhones?

Tags: iphone, ios

My husband and I both just upgraded to iOS 8.3.  Now I notice that if I have a missed call it shows up on *his* notice screen and all my calls show up in his recent call history (and vice versa).

Both phones don't ring and they don't need to be near each other or connected by Wi-Fi.  We do share an iTunes account.

How do I stop sharing call history between the two phones?

Comment: Are you both using the same Apple ID?

Comment: I suggest that you move to different Apple IDs and use [Family Sharing](https://www.apple.com/icloud/family-sharing/) for whatever purchase sharing you need.

Comment: Agree with different apple id's  With iOS 8.3 and 10.10.x your phone will ring on devices with the same apple id in the same network

Answer (score 14):

If you are on the same Apple ID that is going to happen.
You can set up your own Apple ID, including @icloud.com email address for free and then link it with your husband's account for the purchasing of apps, music, etc., using [Family Sharing](https://www.apple.com/icloud/family-sharing/)

4 people in my household are on iDevices and each one has their own Apple ID or iCloud address...but it is all linked to one account and we use family sharing.

Just make sure your husband doesn't set it so that he has to "approve" every purchase you make! ;)

Comment: ... And then that second user will need their own iCloud storage plan for backups and lose access to the iCloud Photo Library you both may have enjoyed sharing...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Apple added a feature called "Handoff"  Turning that to off should stop call history from syncing. 
Settings --> General --> Handoff

Comment: Does handoff really mix call history between two iPhones?

Comment: I think so. It drove my grandparents crazy!

Comment: It indeed seems to work with my parents phone. As surprising that it sounds the handoff feature seems to be source of this problem